# Welcome to MathOverflow Guys!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Today we had many MathOverflow users as new users of MESE and some others who added their first post. I would like to say welcome to these guys as a sign of MESE hospitality.

**Question.** How can we encourage more and more MathOverflow users to participate in MESE?

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion, the best way to advertise the site to MO-users (and I assume the same is true for math.SE users) is just to create an interesting site.

These sites' communities where repeatedly informed about this site's existence. I think people are aware of it by now. And, I think we should *not* do more direct broad advertizing there. I rather feel what was done so far is already at the threshold of what is considered annoying.

There might be room for some very targeted advertizing: if somebody knows of some (old) questions that got closed as off-topic there but would be on-topic here, they could leave a comment on it to point this out to OP. But, even with this I would be careful.

Let us not oversell the site. Let us work on making it better.

Comment: What is your idea about a simple little meta post in MathOverflow by you? I think it could be really useful and pleasant.

Comment: There is already a meta post on MathOverflow, by Brian Rushton, IIRC, to draw attention to the start of public beta.

Comment: This sounds like the Eddie van Halen conundrum:

Comment: **Bill:** Ted, while I agree that, in time, our band will be most triumphant, the truth is Wyld Stallyns will never be a super band until we have Eddie Van Halen on guitar.

**Ted:** Yes, Bill, but I do not believe we will get Eddie Van Halen until we have a triumphant video.

**Bill:** Ted, it's pointless to have a triumphant video before we even have decent instruments.

**Ted:** Well, how can we have decent instruments when we don't really even know how to play?

**Bill:** That is why we NEED Eddie Van Halen!

**Ted:** And THAT is why we need a triumphant video.

**Bill, Ted:** EXCELLENT!

Comment: @user1729 not sure what you mean. But there are some here already that (it is hoped) can create something good, or at least solid. I think we should be patient and persitent. The site *should* grow slowly and steadily, not explosively.

Comment: Agreed! I think there are many questions that this site would be perfect for that MO and MSE simply are not appropriate for. The word will spread.